# How to get the control value (or) element using webworker?

Tags: javascript

## HTML file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <title></title>]]]
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function syncMe() {
                debugger;
                var worker = new Worker("Scripts/dowork.js");
                worker.addEventListener("message", function (evt) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(evt.data);
                });
                worker.postMessage(txtname.value);
            }

        </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>

    <input type="text" id="txtname" />
    <input type="button" id="btnName" value="submit" onclick="syncMe()" />

</body>
</html>
```

## JS file

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
```

Here am passing the static value by `worker.postmessage('txtname.value')` from HTML file to JS file. But I want to access the value or element from thread method i.e. in JS file.

Comment: you cannot access `dom` from web worker

Comment: Simply `document.getElementById("txtname").onchange = function(e) { worker.postMessage(this.value); }`?

Answer (score 0):

Web Workers cannot access the DOM, so you must do DOM-related work in your main JS thread, or pass static values to your worker.

If your value is changing, you should :

- add a listener on the 'change' event of your element.
- send another `message` event with the updated value to your worker
- write a function to handle the updated data in the `message` listener

Reference, from [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers):

> You can run whatever code you like inside the worker thread, with some
>   exceptions. For example, you can't directly manipulate the DOM from
>   inside a worker, or use some default methods and properties of the
>   window object.